# Fragment exit transition doesn't play between two instances of the same Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

I built a very primitive app consisting of one activity and two fragments. From `Fragment1` you can either navigate to another instance of `Fragment1` or to `Fragment2`. When navigating between two fragments, I'm setting an enter and exit transition.

For some reason, the exit transition only plays when I'm navigating from `Fragment1` to `Fragment2`, never between two instances of `Fragment1`. Here's the relevant code from `Fragment1`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSame).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nextFragment(new Fragment1());
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.buttonDifferent).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nextFragment(new Fragment2());
        }
    });

}

private void nextFragment(Fragment frag) {
    setExitTransition(
            TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.enter_exit));

    frag.setEnterTransition(
            TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.enter_exit));

    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() 
            .replace(R.id.layoutContent1, frag) 
            .addToBackStack(null) 
            .commit();
}
```

Here's a demonstration of the behavior:

[image]

Is there a way to make the exit transition play when going between two instances of the same Fragment?

**EDIT:**

It seems the problem is that both fragments use views with the same ID so the framework assumes they should be part of a shared element transition. The problem disappears when I copy the layout and modify all the IDs. However, I'm still looking for a solution that doesn't involve copying all the layouts.

Comment: have you tried transaction.setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit); rather than trying on setFragmentAnimation?

Comment: I specifically want to use Lollipop style transitions.